# You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles

Tags: android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

When I have used new version of google play console there is error showing, When I uploaded the appbundle or apk there are error message shows
[image]

I have tried looking for the solution on google but I don't find any solution relative to my problem.

When I clicked on Review release there are message showing (You cannot remove all production APKs and Android App Bundles)

[image]

Comment: You need to reach out to Play developer support.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the version name & code then upload it. I have already uploaded  apk with same version name & code but with stagged rollout of 35 percent. When I was uploading aab file was getting the error. Resolved after increasing the increasing the version name & code value.

Answer (score 1):

I found that solution.
When I uploaded the `.aab`, I found that error too.
So I built the `.apk` and then I released it  again. It was not showing an error and completed the release.
I think before your previous version is an `.apk` and now the uploaded file type is an `.aab`.

Is that right?

Comment: uploading a new APK build worked for me as well

Comment: I tried and got the same error, uploading a new apk didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Kindly update compileSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion to

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
}
```